# AWS Lightsail - MYSQL DB Stuck In Storage Full (240GB)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Am using an AWS lightsail MySQL instance, which is now stuck in **Storage Full** mode. The system is not allowing to take backup or snapshot as well, once I restore from the previous point it also gets storage full (since 240GB is maximum capacity in Lightsail)
any idea how to handle this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to connect via ssh?

Comment: thanks Ali, is it possible to ssh into lightsail MySQL instance ? didn't find any option for that.

Comment: You first must create a new Lightsail instance to get started accessing your Lightsail database via the command line. I recommend basing your instance on Lightsail’s LAMP blueprint because there are MySQL command line tools already installed. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-lightsail-database-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: No luck, throwing ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server.

Comment: Do you have the 3306 open on the DB instance? for the new instance ip?

Comment: P2P in the same zone is enabled, but in db instance unable to enable public mode, shows the same storage full error.

Comment: if you go to the network tab on the web console do you see a firewall rule?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to contact aws customer support. Have a look at the below thread.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=297856

Comment: Thanks, Manjeet, did that but they asked for premium support and no one responded in the forum.

Comment: Are you able to lightsail console? https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-connecting-to-your-mysql-database

Comment: anyone had this fixed so far?